# React. How to use the keys in setState with array indexes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, this is my code. I have a simple question just about how I can use the `state` element with indexin `key`? In this case I need to set the different values for different `data` index elements.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Doughnut} from 'react-chartjs-2';

class Chart extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            labels: ["All", "Done", "Active"],
            datasets: [{
                label: "Todos",
                backgroundColor: 'grey',
                borderColor: 'green',
                data: [0, 0, 0]
            }]
        };
    }

    getTodosList = (todos) => {
        const all = [];
        const active = [];
        const done = [];

        todos.filter(todo => {
            if (todo.status === 'active') {
                active.push(todo);
            } else if (todo.status === 'all') {
                all.push(todo);
            } else if (todo.status === 'done') {
                done.push(todo);
            }
        });

        this.setState({
            datasets[0].data[0]: all, // error
            datasets[0].data[1]: active, // error
            datasets[0].data[2]: done // error
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple:

```
this.setState({
    datasets: [...this.state.datasets,
        {
            data: [all.length, active.length, done.length]
        }
    ]
});
```

Start to think like Redux think. Use pure functions. It's will help you. Also I understand based on your starts `data` - you probably need to use the `length` of your `items`...

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` function doesn't know which object it has to replace with your code. You're also not accessing the datasets variable properly, it should be `this.state.datasets`. You could do something like:

```
let datasets = this.state.datasets.slice();
datasets[0].data[0] = all;
datasets[0].data[1] = active;
datasets[0].data[2] = done;
this.setState({datasets});
```